# Angular2 need to click twice to retrieve JSON and generate HTML

Tags: angular

In my template I have a button to trigger the following method:

```
getResults() {
        this.resultService.getResultsAsTree(this.disk1.id, this.disk2.id, this.mode)
            .subscribe(
                results => this.json = results,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

        this.getHTML();
    }
```

The method subscribes to a service which retrieves a JSON object, saves it into the `this.json` property.
Immediately afterwards it will call the `this.getHTML()` function which should format the JSON into HTML in a tree view through a recursive method:

```
getHTML() {
        this.html = '';
        this.html += '<div class=\"jstree\"><ul>';
        this.structureAsTree(this.json);
        this.html += '</ul></div>';
    }



    structureAsTree(obj: Object) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (!this.isEmpty(obj[key])) { 
                this.html += '<li>' + key + '<ul>';
                this.structureAsTree(obj[key]);
                this.html += '</ul></li>';
            } else {
                this.html += '<li>' + key + '</li>';
            }
        }

    }
```

**Problem**

Unfortunately, I have to click the button twice in order to show the rendered HTML. However, from the console I already see that the first click retrieved the JSON object.

I assume that the xhr call is asynchronous and so `this.json` is empty when the HTML is being created.

Any hint how to resolve this so data is displayed on the first click?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
getResults() {
    this.resultService.getResultsAsTree(this.disk1.id, this.disk2.id, this.mode)
        .subscribe(
            results => this.json = results, // what to do with result
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error), // what to do if you get error
            () => this.getHTML(); // what to do after you get the result
}
```

Code after `() =>` is executed after you get data from http request. Http request is asynchronous operation and that's the reason why you can't generate HTML with your current code on the first click - `this.getHTML()` is called before your request is finished.

Comment: that worked, however my applied JQuery plugin Jstree doesn't get applied and is not rendering the data as a tree anymore. Marking this source problem as solved. Thanks.